# LeafletModule could not be resolved to an NgModule class in Ivy

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-modules, ngx-leaflet

I'm developing an angular project with ngx-leaflet.
After running `ng serve` in the console, the following error appears:

```
Error: node_modules/@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/dist/leaflet/leaflet.module.d.ts:1:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet) which declares LeafletModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

1 export declare class LeafletModule {
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It is imported in the app.module.ts:

```
import { LeafletModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';
```

Also in the @NgModule in app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config),
    AngularFireAnalyticsModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    LeafletModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Is this a known issue or am I just missing something and screwing the import up?

Version information:

```
Angular CLI: 11.0.6
Node: 12.18.3
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 10.0.8
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1100.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1100.6
@angular-devkit/core            11.0.6
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.0.6
@angular/cli                    11.0.6
@angular/fire                   6.0.2
@schematics/angular             11.0.6
@schematics/update              0.1100.6
rxjs                            6.5.5
typescript                      3.9.7
```

from package.json:

```
"@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^8.1.0",
"leaflet": "^1.7.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated my local angular version to `11.0.8` and now the import works properly. Nothing else was changed, other than also updating rxjs to `6.6.3`, which I doubt is related.
I suppose the error happens with `10.0.8` specifically.